# CLion C++17 boost: No member named xxx in namespace

Tags: c++, boost, clion

I'm setting up a C++17 + boost 1.76.0 project in Clion 2018.3, with this minimal code:

```
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  auto const address = boost::asio::ip::make_address(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

In my CMakeLists.txt I have correctly setup the C++ version:

```
add_definitions(-std=c++17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
```

And the project compiles and run fine. But Clion shows the following error on the make_address line:

> No member named 'make_address' in namespace 'boost::asio::ip'

CTRL-hover on the method name correctly shows the doc, and CTRL-click correctly opens the header file.

Are we supposed to do something else to tel Clion which C++ version are we using?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the IDE and compiler don't agree in the version of boost. These functions are not specific toi a language version, but I think were introduced in a relatively recent Boostt release

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had 2 Boost versions installed on the system, one shipped with ROS (I didn't know that) and v1.76.0 that I compiled to get boost::asio. Looks like Clion was using the one of ROS which older.

Uninstalling v1.76.0 system-wide and adding it back as a header library in the project fixed these false errors, though Clion now takes forever to anaylise the code (despite I excluded the libs folder). Using only the version shipped with ROS would be the best solution for someone not needed the latest additions of Boost (but I do).